# Python cgi script displays output in the browser only after its completion

Tags: python, cgi

I noticed that the python cgi script displays the output only after it has completed its execution, Is there a way, I could make the script to continue its execution and print the results continously. I found that If I run the script "abc.py" as such in Apache, then output is displayed continously (script continuing its execution), however on calling script from another script doesn't works.

Below is the code :- (abc.py)

```
import sys, time
#sys.stdout.write('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n')

#print '<html><body>'
for i in range(10):
    print '<div>%i</div>'%i
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want to run this script from another CGI script. Now when I am calling this script (in Apache using below script), the output is printed only after its completion. Is there a way to fix it.

```
print 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
print '<html><body>'

PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
pd = subprocess.Popen(['abc.py'],
  stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdou, stder = pd.communicate()
sys.stdout.write(stdou)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the browser waiting for the closing `</html>` tag to render the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code

abc.py

```
#!/grid/common/bin/python
import sys, time

for i in range(10):
    print str(i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Main script

```
#!/grid/common/bin/python
import sys, time
import subprocess
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'

print '<html><body>'

PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
pd = subprocess.Popen(['abc.py'],
                        stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
while True:
    output = pd.stdout.read(1)
    if output == '' and pd.poll() != None:
      break
    if output != '':
      sys.stdout.write(output)
      sys.stdout.flush()
```